# How to stop PHP Mailer from appending all email address on every email?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been trying many different ways to prevent PHP Mailer from appending every email address coming from my DB to every single email.

I feel it doesn't look right for every user to receive an email from my website and being able to see a few other thousand emails appended to that same email as well.

Here's my code, I already tried to many diferent things:

```
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $query_select);

if($select_to == 'all'){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $user_email = $row['user_email']; 
        $send_to = $user_email;

        $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'My website');
        $mail->addAddress($send_to); 

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject_email;
        $mail->Body    = $content_email;
        $mail->AltBody = $content_email;
    }
} else {
    if($select_to == 'single'){
        $send_to = $to_single_email;
    }
}




if($mail->send()){
    $confirm = 'Sent.';
    $send = array(
        'confirm'=>$confirm
    );
    echo json_encode($send);

} else {
    $confirm = 'There was en error while sending this email.';
    $send = array(
        'confirm'=>$confirm
    );
    echo json_encode($send);
}
```

Comment: You should create a $email object for every email to send and send it inside of while loop, you can also create an associative array when the index would be the user email and the value the confirm data and send the array encoded to json at the end of the process of sending all emails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$mail->send()` will send to all addresses via a single message. Instead you need to send *one message per recipient.*

The `while()` loop would be refactored similar to:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $user_email = $row['user_email']; 
    $send_to = $user_email;

    $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'My website');
    $mail->addAddress($send_to); 

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject_email;
    $mail->Body    = $content_email;
    $mail->AltBody = $content_email;
    $mail->send();
    $mail->clearAllRecipients();
}
```

The call to [`clearAllRecipients()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/phpmailerclearallrecipients/) will clear out the previous addresses that would otherwise accumulate via `addAddress()`

You'll also need to add the error checking within the loop for each call of `send()`

Comment: Check out the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. It does the same thing, but is a bit more efficient.

Comment: @leepowers Wow, thanks.. it does work right, I did this yesterday but I left $mail->send() outside the loop so I can send my email confirmation string via json, I think I'll need to figure out a better way to confirm if those emails were sent? Since if I keep using if($mail->send()){...} it will send the emails twice.

Comment: @Synchro Tried this too and seems better, again.. I used this yesterday but keept the $mail->send() outside the loop for email confirmation via json.. I do like this method better, I never used $mail->send() inside the loop to keep the confirmation working though

Comment: Putting the send outside the loop makes no sense. You can store the sent status of each message inside the loop, then return the whole array afterwards.